Projections onto orthocomplement 2D planes in 4D
From this post,

It is possible to go another route and generalize. The orthogonal projection $\pi_2:U\to\Pi_2$ may be restricted to $\Pi_1$, and it has a "hypervolume distortion factor" $\lambda$. That is, the effect of $\pi_2$ on any region $D\subset\Pi_1$ with finite volume $\mathrm{vol}(D)$ is to first shrink it along the $v_1$-axis by a factor of $\lambda$ (and flip it if $\lambda<0$), then rotate $\Pi_1$'s $v_1$-axis through $U$ to $\Pi_2$'s $v_2$-axis, to get a region with hypervolume $\mathrm{vol}(\pi_2(D))=\lambda\,\mathrm{vol}(D)$. This is just like how determinants work on a fixed space. This definition of $\lambda=\cos\phi$ applies to any two equal-dimension subspaces $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$, regardless of their intersection's (co)dimension.

Then I think the following would be true:

In $\mathbb R^4$, let $U$ be a 2D subspace, let $\pi_1$ be the projection from $U$ onto $xy$-plane and $\pi_2$ be the projection from $U$ onto $zw$-plane, then $\det\pi_1+\det\pi_2\le1$, and $\det\pi_1+\det\pi_2=1$ if and only if $\pi_1,\pi_2$ both preserve angles (same as similarity transformations in Euclidean geometry).

My proof is the following:
$$\det\pi_1=\sqrt{\det(\pi_1^\top\pi_1)}\le\frac{\operatorname{tr}(\pi_1^\top\pi_1)}2
$$
equality holds iff $\pi_1^T\pi_1$ have all eigenvalues equal, in this case, $\pi_1$ is orthogonal matrix. Similarly,
$$\det\pi_2=\sqrt{\det(\pi_2^\top\pi_2)}\le\frac{\operatorname{tr}(\pi_2^\top\pi_2)}2
$$
Adding,
$$
\det\pi_1+\det\pi_2\le\frac{\operatorname{tr}(\pi_1^\top\pi_1+\pi_2^\top\pi_2)}2=1
$$
as required.
I try to generalize the above to two orthocomplement $n$-dimensional subspaces in $\Bbb R^{2n}$

In $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, let $U$ be a $n$-dimensional hyperplane, $\Pi_1,\Pi_2$ be orthocomplement $n$-dimensional subspaces, and $\pi_i:U\to\Pi_i$ be the orthogonal projections, then $(\det\pi_1)^{2/n}+(\det\pi_2)^{2/n}\le1$

Is this correct?

You might be interested in this:
https://imgur.com/a/PXDpzJ9
It summaries my answer taken from a discussion here;
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910920/angle-between-two-planes-in-four-dimensions
The formulas generalize to $n$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.
